# how to upload an image from django rest framework using browse button?

Tags: python-2.7, django-rest-framework

i am new to django-rest-framework,i am unble to get the image as browse button in my rest framework,i am getting text field,here is my code as follows...........

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from serializers import *
 from rest_framework import viewsets

class newsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
"""
API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
"""
queryset = news.objects.all()
serializer_class = newsSerializer

class news_categoriesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

queryset = news_categories.objects.all()
serializer_class = news_categoriesSerializer
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode

class news_categories(models.Model):
cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
def __unicode__(self):
    return smart_unicode(self.cat_name)

def Content_files(instance, filename):
return '/'.join(['Media','News Image', filename])

class news(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
description = models.TextField()
cat_id = models.ForeignKey('news_categories')
image = models.FileField(upload_to=Content_files,null=True)
date = models.DateField()
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
def __unicode__(self):
   return smart_unicode(self.name)
```

serializers.py

```
from django.forms import widgets
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import *

class newsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = news
    fields = ('url','id','name','description','cat_id','image','date')

class news_categoriesSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = news_categories
    fields = ('url','id','cat_name')
```

Any one can Help me?Thanks in Advance....

Comment: plz any one can help me?

Comment: i got it django rest framework==2.4.4 is the version to exact rest framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem with settings.py and version of rest framework ,use 2.4.4

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same problem when I updated to version 3.0. The solution is to define the FileField or ImageField in your serializer using a style attribute:

`file = serializers.FileField(style = {'input_type': 'file'})`